# lazarus form creation

Tags: forms, lazarus

The following code is from http://wiki.freepascal.org/MySQLDatabases

```
procedure TFormTryMySQL.OpenQueryButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowQueryForm := TShowQueryForm.Create(self);
 ShowQueryForm.Datasource1.DataSet := SQLQuery1;
 SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := CommandEdit.Text;
 SQLQuery1.Open;
 ShowQueryForm.ShowModal;
 ShowQueryForm.Free;
 SQLQuery1.Close;
end;
```

I'm new to Lazarus. Can someone please explain the line **ShowQueryForm := TShowQueryForm.Create(self);**? I'm particularly curious about:

1. Why do we need to CREATE a form programmatically?
2. What is the TShowQueryForm?
3. My form is without a T. How come the SQLQuery1
   control can access the data on the new form?

I'm sorry if this is not a well-phrased question but I AM confused here :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1.    Why do we need to CREATE a form programmatically?
```

It's optional. You can let forms autocreate, as vfclists says, in which the designer adds the form creation to the LPR. (just like Delphi btw).

```
 2. What is the TShowQueryForm? My form is without a T.
```

The type of the form. So you have a variable name xxxsomeForm with Txxxsomeform as its specific type.

```
 3. How come the SQLQuery1 control can access the data on the new form?
```

Other way around. The grids, or whatever db aware controls are in showqueryform get their data from a datasource object. In the 2nd line:

```
 ShowQueryForm.Datasource1.DataSet := SQLQuery1;
```

the sqlquery component of the current form is assigned to the dataset on the newly created form.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The last point is what puzzles me. I thought the two forms contain some objects (eg: Datasource) and these are supposed to be private to the forms. I'm puzzled on how the second form can simply be assigned the data source of the first.

Comment: designtime components are "published" by default, which is "public" + "generate rtti". It is not a terribly nice solution, (nice would be to use a datamodule) but not terribly wrong either

Answer (score 0):

If the form is automatically created in the Project | Forms Auto-Create sas one which is automatically created when the application starts there is no need to create it.

The fact that the form being displayed is a Modal form, means it is like a dialog which is not created automatically, but only on demand.

Comment: Thanks vfclists. This is why I put the question. The form was created in design view already. So I didn't see any sense in using the create method to show it. I wonder if there's something to do with populating data in the grid...